# Canonical MVC Model for Java Web?

Tags: model-view-controller

I am attending a training course where they presented the following model, with a claim that all modern Java web frameworks more or less implement it.  I think it is too sweeping of a statement but I want to get it verified.  Here is the model:

[image]